# Не отображается картинка background

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

У меня не отображается картинка в следующем теге:

```
<b-icon v-if="displayShowHistory && checkRole('showHistory')" class="backlight show-modal-icon" id="historyDoc" @click="showHistory"></b-icon>

.b-icon#historyDoc {
  background: url("../assets/history.png") center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 32px;
}
```

При этом в консоли со стилями отображается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы иконка корректно отображалась на странице? Сейчас ничего не отображается.

Comment: Возможно надо прописать кроме ширины еще и высоту картинки ?

Comment: Bogdan, Не помогает.